# SSL付ロードバランサとnginxを使う方法について

Tags: nginx, ssl

現在ロードバランサとnginxの設定を行っています。
構成としては、ロードバランサがあり、そこからnginxサーバに振り分け、さらにnginxサーバから実サーバに振り分けます。
ロードバランサにSSL証明書をインストールするので、nginxサーバおよび実サーバはSSL化しない想定です。
この場合、nginxサーバでhttps(port 443)を振り分けるためには、どのように設定したら良いでしょうか？
nginxサーバにもSSL証明書のインストールが必要でしょうか？

nginxのnginx.confで以下のように指定しただけでは駄目でした。

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

ロードバランサで設定する、nginxサーバのポート番号で`listen`するとよいと思います。

＃ロードバランサでSSL終端しているので、ロードバランサ - nginxサーバ間は復号されたHTTPが流通すると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。おっしゃるとおりロードバランサでHTTPS化してるので、nginxサーバはHTTPを意識すれば良いですね。上記方法を試してみます。